# Cant get "else" statement to work with jquery-waypoint

Tags: if-statement, jquery-waypoints

i want to use "a waypoint" with j query and it works fine besides when i try to add an "else" statement. the idea is to scroll the text "WORK AT THIS POINT" to the top and all the text will fo to the left. It works just fine except for when i try to add the "else".

ive commented the parts that i added which stops it from working and my fiddle is below.

Please help

```
$('#waypoint').waypoint(function() {
  //  alert('You have scrolled to an entry.');
        $("p").animate({left:"300px"});
}else{ // NEWLY ADDED WORKS WITHOUT 
        $("p").animate({left:"0px"}); // NEWLY ADDED WORKS WITHOUT        
}, {
    offset: '0%'
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/P3XnN/386/

Comment: Not 100% sure what syntax you're going for, but the `else` clause is being appended to the function. Are you missing an `if`? Try checking out your errors in your Javascript console as well.

Comment: Nope i don't think it needs an "if" statement just to work, it works fine without it but with the added "else" the code is broken.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears you can capture a `direction` argument in the function:

```
$('#waypoint').waypoint(function(direction) {
  if(direction==="down") {
    $("p").animate({left:"300px"});
  } else {
    $("p").animate({left:"0px"});
  }
}, {
  offset: '0%'
});
```

Or go here for the demo: http://jsfiddle.net/P3XnN/404/